# JS (Jquery) .keydown event that triggers an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey everyone I am trying to figure out how to make the jquery keydown event on the entire page. In this code instance if a person presses "q" then an alert pops up saying "anything here.". But my issue is that the js I wrote seems to no work properly. Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).keydown(function () {
  if (event.which == 81) {
     alert("TEST!");
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **FYI:** order of script should be **1. jQuery 2. jQueryUI**
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to pass the event into your function :)

```
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
  ...
});
```

Also, as pointed out by @praveen in the comments to OP, script order should be swapped so jquery is included before the jquery-ui script.